# Will a graphics card work on my motherboard?

Tags: motherboard

I would like to know if my motherboard can support a graphics/video card, I have an HP Mulberry motherboard but I don't know if the pci slot on this motherboard is compatible with a graphics card, let alone which kind of card I would need for the pci slot on this motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03955263

It has

> Integrated AMD HD 8330 Graphics

and doesn't support additional graphics cards.